# For MM/DD/YYYY text, display only that text which is not entered by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, date

I have a page like below image
[image]

According to my requirement, user is allowed to enter digits from the keypad that is provided on the page only. So input field is readonly.

Now I am trying to get is, when user start entering month then other text should remain in text field until user types that. e.g. 05/DD/YYYY like this. And accordingly that text will be hide.

If I placed placeholder then when user starts entering digits all text gone. I don't want that. So I have taken "MM/DD/YYYY" text in seperate `span tag`.

```js
var Memory  = "0",    // initialise memory variable
    Current = "",     //   and value of Display ("current" value)
    Operation = 0,    // Records code for eg * / etc.
    MAXLENGTH = 8;    // maximum number of digits before decimal!

function format(input, format, sep) {
  var output = "";
  var idx = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < format.length && idx < input.length; i++) {
    output += input.substr(idx, format[i]);
    if (idx + format[i] < input.length) output += sep;
    idx += format[i];
  }
  output += input.substr(idx);
  return output;
}

function AddDigit(dig) {        //ADD A DIGIT TO DISPLAY (keep as 'Current')
  if (Current.indexOf("!") == -1) { //if not already an error
    if ((eval(Current) == undefined) &&
        (Current.indexOf(".") == -1)) {
      Current = dig;
      document.calc.display.focus();
    } else {
      Current = Current + dig;
      document.calc.display.focus();
    }
    Current = Current.toLowerCase(); //FORCE LOWER CASE
  } else {
    Current = "Hint! Press 'Clear'";  //Help out, if error present.
  }

  if (Current.length > 0) {
    Current = Current.replace(/\D/g, "");
    Current = format(Current, [2, 2, 4], "/");
  }
  document.calc.display.value = Current.substring(0, 10);
  document.getElementById("cursor").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function Clear() {               //CLEAR ENTRY
  Current = "";
  document.calc.display.value = Current;
  document.calc.display.focus();
  document.getElementById("cursor").style.visibility = "visible";
  //setInterval ("cursorAnimation()", 5000);
}

function backspace() {
  Current = document.calc.display.value;
  var num = Current;
  Current = num.slice(0,num.length - 1);
  document.calc.display.value = Current;
  document.calc.display.focus();
  document.getElementById("cursor").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function cursorAnimation() {
  $("#cursor").animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, "fast", "swing").animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, "fast", "swing");
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------->
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("cursor").style.visibility = "visible";
  //setInterval ("cursorAnimation()", 1000);
});
```

```css
.intxt1 {
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* border: 0; */
  width: 1017px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-family: Droid Sans Mono;
  background: #fff;
}
.txtplaceholder {
  font-family: "Droid Sans Mono";
  color: #D7D7D7;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 219px;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: 10 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cursor {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 32px;
  top: 2px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form Name="calc" method="post">
  <div style="position:relative">
    <span id="cursor">_</span>
    <span class="txtplaceholder">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
    <span style="z-index:100">
      <input class="intxt1" autocomplete="off" id="pt_dob" name="display" value="" type="text" readonly>
    </span>
    <button class="cancel-icon" type="reset" onClick="Clear()"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="num_keypad1" style=" margin-top:19px;">
    <!-- Screen and clear key -->
    <div class="num_keys">
      <!-- operators and other keys -->
      <span id="key1" onClick="AddDigit('1')">1</span>
      <span id="key2" onClick="AddDigit('2')">2</span>
      <span id="key3" onClick="AddDigit('3')">3</span>
      <span id="key4" onClick="AddDigit('4')">4</span>
      <span id="key5" onClick="AddDigit('5')">5</span>
      <span id="key6" onClick="AddDigit('6')">6</span>
      <span id="key7" onClick="AddDigit('7')">7</span>
      <span id="key8" onClick="AddDigit('8')">8</span>
      <span id="key9" onClick="AddDigit('9')">9</span>
      <span id="key0" onClick="AddDigit('0')" style="width: 200px;">0</span>
      <span id="keyback" class="clear" onClick="backspace()">   <div class="num_xBox">X</div></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

With the above Html code I am getting below result:
 [image]

Problems coming are below:

1. My digits are going below the text "MM/DD/YYYY". I am not getting how should I get my digits above that text
2. How should I hide the text which is entered by user and display other accordingly e.g. "MM" should hide if user enters 05 and display other text like this "05/DD/YYYY".

Can anyone please help me in this?

**NOTE:** With input type=date or by any other plugins I can achieve above functionality but my requirement is different. I have to achieve this with HTML, CSS, JS only.

Comment: The effect you're looking for is 'input masking'. If you google there are hundreds of plugins which will do this for you already

Comment: Yes I know that plugins but my requirement is different. I can't use default plugins as my input field is readonly and user has to enter digits from keypad that is provided on page. I have mention that in my question as well. As I have to use provided keypad only so I have managed all functionality in Javascript(mentioned in the question).

Comment: I read your question. Neither of those restrictions affect the use of a masking plugin

Comment: The plugins that I have seen in which user can type digits in text box directly from their native keyboard. But in my case, user is not allowed to type digits from their native keyboard. So I have made my input textbox readonly and applied JS to enter digits from keypad. User must have to use keypad provided(as shown in image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a ready built data picker for this kind of thing as it would have all the error checking in built to ensure you enter a date in the correct format.

The way you are doing it, you are not able to check if the day is valid until you have entered the month, by which time the user will have to backspace and it will be a very slow and clunky process which is not very user friendly.

Anyway, if you persist with a number pad, here is how I would do it.

1. put the date in a global array
2. have a global index counter
3. add and remove values based on the index counter

The following is a very quick example of the above

```js
var dateBits = ["D", "D", "M", "M", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"],
    letters = ["D", "D", "M", "M", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"],
    input = document.getElementById('pt_dob'),
    currentIndex = 0;
  
function makeDate() {
  return dateBits[0] + dateBits[1] + "/" + dateBits[2] + dateBits[3] + "/" + dateBits[4] + dateBits[5] + dateBits[6] + dateBits[7];
}

function AddDigit(number) {
  dateBits[currentIndex] = number;
  if (currentIndex < 8) {
   currentIndex++;
  }

  input.value = makeDate();
}

function RemoveDigit() {
  if (currentIndex > 0) {
   currentIndex--;
  }
  
  dateBits[currentIndex] = letters[currentIndex];
  input.value = makeDate();
}

function Clear() {
  for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    dateBits[i] = letters[i];
  }
  
  currentIndex = 0;
  input.value = makeDate();
}

input.value = makeDate();  // run this line onload or include this whole script at the bottom of the page to get your input to start with your text
```

```css
.intxt1 {
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* border: 0; */
  width: 1017px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-family: Droid Sans Mono;
  background: #fff;
}

#cursor {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 32px;
  top: 2px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.num_keys > span {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form Name="calc" method="post">
  <div style="position:relative"><span id="cursor">_</span>
    <span class="txtplaceholder">MM/DD/YYYY</span><span style="z-index:100"><input class="intxt1" autocomplete="off" id="pt_dob" name="display" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly></span>
    <button class="cancel-icon" type="reset" onClick="Clear(); return false;">clear</button>
  </div>

  <div class="num_keypad1" style=" margin-top:19px;">
    <!-- Screen and clear key -->

    <div class="num_keys">
      <!-- operators and other keys -->
      <span id="key1" onClick="AddDigit('1')">1</span>
      <span id="key2" onClick="AddDigit('2')">2</span>
      <span id="key3" onClick="AddDigit('3')">3</span>

      <span id="key4" onClick="AddDigit('4')">4</span>
      <span id="key5" onClick="AddDigit('5')">5</span>
      <span id="key6" onClick="AddDigit('6')">6</span>

      <span id="key7" onClick="AddDigit('7')">7</span>
      <span id="key8" onClick="AddDigit('8')">8</span>
      <span id="key9" onClick="AddDigit('9')">9</span>

      <span id="key0" onClick="AddDigit('0')" style="width: 200px;">0</span>
      <span id="keyback" class="clear" onClick="RemoveDigit()">   <div class="num_xBox">X</div></span>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. I have applied your code on my page. The problems coming are the text "DD/MM/YYYY" is not coming in my text box when I load my page. In your case the text displays when we run the code. How is this happening? And another problem is of "Clear" function. I had made clear function (Clear()) on click of cross button which is in the text box. You have not mentioned that function. Due to "type=reset" its clearing text but when I start entering new number, the previous entered date gets stored. please help me in the "Clear()" function as well which should not store previous date

Comment: I have edited the above with comments of what starts off your box with text, a clear function (please note the change to the onclick of the button) and to stop the input from auto-completing (added attribute to the input)

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "DD/MM/YYYY";

$(".textbox").on("focus blur", function(){
    $(".wrapper").toggleClass("focused");
});

$(".wrapper").click(function (e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
        var b = $(".textbox", this).focus();
    }
}).trigger("click");

$(".wrapper > .textbox").on("input", function(){
    var ipt = $(this).text().replace(/\u00A0/g, " ");
    $(".gray").text(text.substr(ipt.length, text.length));
}).trigger("input");
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7sD2r/22/

Answer (score -1):

If ive understood all well. I think the one solution is to store user input in hidden field. Then get this input to split digits and return to visible input value that consists of splitted values etc.